# Linux router with UFW - how to block internet access for an IP address

Tags: router, ufw

I have an Ubuntu machine setup as a home internet router. I would like to block internet access for particular IP address or mac address. Is it easily possible? I use UFW as a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can set iptables filter by ip address, for example:

iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -s 192.168.1.100 -j DROP

There are a lot more choices better than ubuntu:

1. [WFilter NG firewall](http://www.wfilterros.com), free for 50 users, with web filter, application control, internet usage monitor...
2. Untangle firewall, USD 50 for home license.
3. Sophos NG firewall, free for home license.

Comment: thanks! but it did not work for me. Later I realized it is possible to set range of ip addresses which will be nat-ed instead of the whole subnet, so I can exclude particular IP address by defining range which the ip address is not part of. Example (add to /etc/ufw/before.rules): `-A POSTROUTING -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.99 -o wwan0 -j MASQUERADE`